# iOS get width of each character in a string for a given font

Tags: android, ios, nsstring, uifont, robovm

I would like a similar function to Android's:

```
TextPaint.getTextWidths(String text, int index, int count, float[] widths);
```

Basically what this does is - for a given font, it will return all the individual character widths of that string. I do not need the range (index/count) as I will always be doing it for the full string.

The following is actually Java RoboVM bindings of iOS functions, but it should be fairly easy to understand the classes I am using and how. I know how to get the bounding box of the string, like this;

```
NSString nsString = new NSString(string);
CGSize dim = nsString.getSize(uiFont);
```

Unfortunately the solution is not as simple as interrelating through the characters in the string, because this gives invalid results for complex scripts such as Arabic, where a characters appearance and size is also dependent on it's siblings. Android's `getTextWidths()` deals with this though, so I am hoping there is similar functionality available on iOS.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know RoboVM very well. However, `getString(UIFont)` seems to be a RoboVM extension to `NSString`. You should try `getSize(NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject> attrs)` which usually yields very good results.

Comment: Thanks macmoonshine, but this still just outputs a single CGSize, I don't see how this can give me all the individual char widths of a string?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand why you want compute individual character widths. In any case, the example of Arabic characters is a good example of not doing so.